# Finding the nearest point to a given set of points

Tags: classification, similarities, hierarchical-clustering

I am trying to build an auto-suggestion logic which looks at currently selected items and recommends a list of items to select the next item from.

I can formulate the problem thus:
Given a set of points S = {p1,p2,p3....,pn} for the selected items and another set of points M = {a1,a2,...,am} for the remaining items, I am looking to find the point in M that is "closest to the set" S. The distance metric could be euclidean, cosine or custom (based on different situations). For a specific case, let us only consider cosine similarity. Each point has some coordinates that I can use to compute similarity/distance.

It appears to me that a few things I can try are:

1. Find a representative point in the set S (that representative point may not necessarily exist in S), e.g. the centroid of the points in S, and then find the nearest point from M to the centroid
2. Try some form of hierarchical clustering (it is not necessary that if I apply hierarchical clustering on the union of S and M, points in S will neatly form a cluster)
3. Create a dataset with S union M as rows and add a column with labels 1 and 0 for points from S and M respectively. Fit a classification model and find the point (belonging to M) that the highest probability for class 1

Can I please have some thoughts on what could be the best way to solve this problem, not necessarily limited to the three ideas that I have mentioned above.

Comment: How do you "quantify" the distance of a point to a set of points? Lets take for example the euclidean space. Suppose the points in set M are $A_1, A_2$ and suppose the points in S are $P_1, P_2$ Now lets say distance from $P_1$ to $\mathcal{M}$ are $\{2, 3\}$ and distances $P_2$ to $\mathcal{M}$ are $\{1.5, 4\}$ What will your conclusion be? which point is close to set $\mathcal{M}$ and why?

Comment: Distance is defined between pairs of points. Of course, we can look at some kind of summary statistic for the distances between sets of points, but there are many ways to choose the statistics you want to compare (min of minimum distances, min of median distances, etc). These choices naturally encode information about what "nearest to a set" means to you. Can you [edit] to expand on what problem you're trying to solve and how finding a point nearest to a set solves that problem?

Comment: Also, suppose $\mathcal{M}$ is a simple linear transformation of $\mathcal{P}$ such that $P$ lies in the same vector space as $\mathcal{M}$  with a shift/scale parameters. Note that the plane that supports $\mathcal{M}$ will be parallel to the plane that supports $\mathcal{P}$. How will you determine closeness?. ie think of 2D, points that line on the line $x=2$ eg $\mathcal{M} = \{\{2,3\}, \{2,4\}, \{2,5\}\}$ vs points that lie on line $x=3$ eg $\mathcal{P} = \{\{3,3\}, \{3,4\}, \{3,5\}\}$. How would you approach this?

Comment: It seems it will be impossible to answer this question objectively until you can elaborate on what "closest to" is intended to represent.  Could you explain?

Comment: Are you trying to compute the [Hausdorff distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_distance)?